# How do I restrict web app to be run from particular pc's

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am developing a Zend PHP web application. The application has come quite a long way though its not complete. Its got authentication and all (using username and password). However I have just been requested to restrict the access of some class of users to come from their particular pc's whiles the other users can access it as normal from the web.

I am thinking of using the pc's MAC address to restrict the access. However I know that PHP cannot access the MAC address of the pc's over the Internet. How do I go about this?

**[edit]**

The users will access the application from the regular Internet (its not an Intranet)

Comment: Just an FYI, MAC addresses are stupidly easy to spoof.

Comment: MAC addresses are not typically usable for anything at the application layer. Where would these PCs be? Is this a intranet vs. internet situation? Or are these "certain users" accessing it over the regular internet from random IPs as well?

Comment: They're also not preserved during packet routing, so they probably aren't even sent to the server.

Comment: Are the computers under the control of the organization?

Answer (score 1):

MAC Addresses can be easily changed, IP Addresses Renew, Cookies can be deleted. Its impossible to keep every user assigned to their own PC, but you can use a mixture of cookie and IP verification (and some other headers such as user-agent) to help ensure that the everyday user won't be accessing his account via another computer.

Comment: I've had some limited success modifying the user agent string on PCs to help identify them (even built a firefox add-on to help) - You have to be careful since that can be changed by a user and if they figure it out it can lead to unwanted access.  It works best if the PCs are under control on the organization (locked down, etc)

Answer (score 0):

As you suspect you cannot get any information about MAC addresses over the internet/network. You would have to setup some IP address rules, i.e. allow from 10.1.1.0/24

Answer (score 0):

If the site is still under development, May be you can restrict the access to create usernames
to a few set of people or may be just the administrator. Now you can decide what access rights to give to which user. You can show the authentication right after the page loads.
(if you dont want to change the sites functionality, you can consider adding a extra layer of user authentication while it is in development phase, something like the popup that you see when you try to access your internet modem).